# C++: trying to create event-driven for console (but stuck with a problem)

Tags: c++, windows, console

I am trying to make a event-driven program out of a console that display clock time since start of the program.

I created a function:

```
WORD GetKey(HANDLE input)
{
    INPUT_RECORD Event;
    DWORD Read;

    ReadConsoleInput(input,&Event,1,&Read);

        if(Event.EventType == KEY_EVENT)
        {
            if(Event.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown) 
            {
                return Event.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode;
            }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Then I used it into the main while() loop. However, when I launched the program, it lags (the displaying clock pause for about 3-5 seconds delay). What's more weird to this problem is when I press and hold '1' key, the lag problem just gone.. :

```
WORD LastAction = GetKey(input) //this chunk of code lies in the main while(!quit)
switch(LastAction) 
            {
                case VK_ESCAPE:
                    quit = true;
                    break;
                case '1':
                case VK_NUMPAD1:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
```

Is it because my understanding of ReadConsoleInput() is not sufficient? or my code isn't efficient?

please advise me on this issue

thx

Comment: Did you add something else in your while() loop ?

Comment: Yeah, but that's not an issue, because  it is unrelated to the GetKey() function. Even if i tried removing that part out, it still occur.

Comment: Why are you not using the Read variable?

Comment: I don't know what you are doing, but ReadConsoleInput() blocks until there is something to read.

Answer (score 2):

When there are no events to be read, `ReadConsoleInput` will block waiting for an event. You need to check for available events using `GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents`, then either read events if there are any present, or pause a little while, e.g. `Sleep(10)`, if there's none.

Comment: Or call `ReadConsoleInput` in a separate, event-polling thread?

Comment: IMO pointless, his goal is to process input and otherwise do more or less nothing. No need to introduce the extra complexity.